# SQL Server - For each distinct company count the number of employees

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct

I am trying to create some SQL that will count the number of employees within each company and return only those companies with greater than or equal to `n` employees.

I have the following tables (simplified):

```
CompanyEmployee Table

ID    Name         IsCompany
1     John Joe     0
2     Company Y    1
3     Company X    1
4     Sally Jeff   0
5     James Peach  0
```

```
Employment Table
ID    EmployeeID    CompanyID
1     1             2
2     4             3
3     5             3
```

My desired result for `n=2`:

```
ID    Name         IsCompany
3     Company X    1
```

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT t.* FROM CompanyEmployee AS t 
WHERE t.ID IN ( 
  SELECT DISTINCT (t.ID) 
  FROM CompanyEmployee AS t  
  INNER JOIN Employment AS t0 ON t.ID = t0.CompanyID 
  WHERE t.IsCompany = 1
  GROUP BY t0.CompanyID
  HAVING COUNT(t0.EmployeeID) >= n)
```

But it generates the following error:

```
Column 'CompanyEmployee.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixing companies and employees this way is a bad idea. Using a straight inner join may work as long as the id values between the two different types of rows never intersect. I guess if it's an identity column then that's not supposed to happen.

```
with Companies as (
    select ID as CompanyID, Name
    from CompanyEmployee
    where IsCompany = 1
), Employees as (
    select CompanyID, Name
    from CompanyEmployee where
    IsCompany = 0
)
select c.CompanyID, Name, 1 as IsCompany
from
    Companies as c
    inner join Employment as ec on ec.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
    inner join Employees as e on e.EmployeeID = ce.EmployeeID
group by
    c.CompanyID
having count(*) >= n
```

There is still a straightforward way to do it:

```
select *
from CompanyEmployee
where ID in (
    select CompanyID
    from Employment
    group by CompanyID
    having count(*) >= n)
)
```

Comment: Agree with first sentence, however i really hate to use IN clause because of its "performance" ;) Upvoted!

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that the query plans are quite similar. The optimizer is good at transforming subqueries that way.

Comment: @Maciej I think you may be thinking of a problem in ancient versions of SQL Server. In modern versions, `IN` is generally optimized exactly the same as `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.CompanyId, t2.CompanyName, COUNT(t1.CompanyId)
FROM Employment AS t1 INNER JOIN CompanyEmployee AS t2 ON t1.CompanyId = t2.Id
GROUP BY t1.CompanyId, t2.CompanyName
HAVING COUNT(t1.CompanyId)>=n
```

where **n** is a number of employees...

Comment: Updated... Sorry, i wrote it straight from a head ;)

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly, however shawnt00 provided a more simple solution.

Comment: I don't think it's more simple, but... decision belongs to you ;)

Comment: *More applicable to my project :P